# Looking for more Simplification of JavaScript destructure with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, syntax, destructuring

I've got an array with 100's of attributes that I want to chop down to just a small number in my Type Safe TypeScript object. Here is my code that works but I'm hoping to find a cleaner way that does not make me mention the attribute names twice (avoiding DRY and errors).

```
const {id = 0,username = '....',userFirstName = '.',userLastName = '..'} = response.data;
const userInfoObj : IUserInfo = {id,username,userFirstName,userLastName};
```

This is as far as I could figure out.  Any suggestions to make it simpler?

Comment: The destructure could be avoided if not using the resulting local variables: `const x : Y = {d.id, d.username, ..}`. This potentially saves on the (immediate) duplicate names used.

Comment: Looks like you have an object with 100s of attributes, because that code wouldn't work with an array. Also, can't you just do `const userInfoObj: IUserInfo = response.data`? I mean, you'd get all of the attributes, but it's not like they're sold individually :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is as far as I could figure out. Any suggestions to make it simpler?

There is no syntax for a combined (destructure + structure).

> I've got an array with 100's of attributes

You might need to add some for of codegen to your build pipeline.

Comment: Ouch, I was hoping for something. scared of codegen